# Do we finally have a decent set of parameters of 162173 Ryugu?

Tags: asteroids

"Give a man a watch and he will know the time; give him two and he will never be sure" - this was my impression when reading the Wikipedia article on [162173 Ryugu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/162173_Ryugu).

> Mean diameter:
>
> - 0.865±0.015 km[3]
> - 0.87 km[4]
> - 0.90±0.14 km[5]
> - 0.92±0.12 km[6]
> - 0.980±0.029 km[7]
> - 1.13±0.03 km[8]

And no mass estimates at all.

Now that Hayabusa2 has arrived, do we have solid measurements of Ryugu's size and mass yet?

Comment: Give JAXA some time to collect and process their data. The [papers about 25143 Itokawa](https://doi.org/10.1126/science.1125841) were published 8 months after the Hayabusa 1 encounter.

Comment: @MikeG: okay, then the question can just wait for the answer to become available.

Comment: There is a special session on Hayabusa2 at the Division of Planetary Sciences 50th meeting in October. I would expect the first preliminary science results to be announced there but the data analysis takes time. Volume ans Mass in particular take a while as you have to make sure you've mapped all the surface of the asteroid and sampled the variable gravity field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [science paper](https://science.sciencemag.org/content/364/6437/272.abstract) from 2019 by K. Kitazato *et al.* shows a shape model of the surface in Fig. 2, so  we now indeed know the exact size and  the exact mass, even the surface temperature distribution:

[image: Shape Model of 162173 Ryugu.]

The quoted paper refers to [S. Watanabe et al., Science, 2019](https://science.sciencemag.org/content/364/6437/268) which has all the details

> Ryugu has an oblate body, with an **equatorial radius of 502 ± 2 m and polar-to-equatorial axis ratio of 0.872 ± 0.007**. The total volume obtained from the SPC-based shape model is $0.377 {\rm km}^3$, with an uncertainty of 1.3%. We conducted a gravity measurement during a spacecraft ballistic descent down to 0.85 km from the asteroid surface and a subsequent ballistic ascent up to 5.4 km. The **estimated mass is $4.50\times 10^{11} {\rm kg}$**, with an uncertainty of 1.3%, mainly because of uncertainties in the solar radiation pressure on the spacecraft.

The **highlighting** in the quote is from me.